# SignalR in MVC3, timing and start/connect issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, signalr

I am having a really weird issue with MVC3 and signalr.. I have a simple hub;

```
[HubName("test")]
public class Test: Hub
{
    public object GetStuff()
    {
        return new { dummy = "Test" };
    }
}
```

And some client-side code;

```
var connection = $.connection.test;
connection.start();
connection.getStuff();
```

This throws an error;

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'start'**

If I instead do

```
var connection = $.connection("test");
```

I get a different error;

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'getStuff' jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4**

**POST http://localhost:63021/Controller/test/negotiate 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Note its trying to negotiate under the controller for some reason?

Is there some specific route I need to register? Some other magic I dont know about?

**UPDATE**
So playing a bit with console -- the first version does in fact create an object that has getStuff() which i can call. But signalr throws up because i have to call start() first -- which doesn't exist! The second one creates an object that DOES have start(), but it doesnt have getStuff()..

**UPDATE 2**
Tried doing $.connection.hub.start instead. This seems to work in the console, but not in the page onload.. Possibly start isnt finished before the hub call is made? Is it async?

Comment: Can't say for sure - but it might be case sensitive `getStuff` vs. `GetStuff` for your second case.

Comment: Neither one works, and the negotiate url returns a 404 as it cant exist (hubs are at the root)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting the SignalR connection is not instantaneous. You call to `connection.GetStuff();` may fail if the connection has not yet been established. If you want this code to run after a connection to the hub is established you should use a callback function.

```
var connection = $.connection.test;
$.connection.hub.start(function(){        
    // By convention all exposed hub methods start with lowercase
    connection.getStuff();
});
```

Hub Quickstart: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

In-depth look at SignalR javascript client: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs

Comment: Tried this too -- and set a timer in code. Its the start() method thats this slow. Same exact code but in webforms instead of mvc connects in 0.2 seconds. Under MVC, 3-5 seconds.. some conflict on the MVC side perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the hub portion:

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var connection = $.connection("@Url.Content("~/echo")");